# Very Low Quality flag declined on image-only question

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

Some questions require depiction to illustrate the problem. That's totally fair. But if limited only by images, it may be troublesome to catch the gist of the problem. That's what I figured was the case for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368154/magento-home-page-product-image-path-is-not-complete), which I've flagged as VLQ.

It looks like this:

> [image: images-only]

Two borderline-arbitrary screenshots with one line of text in between.

I admit that professional field is not one of mine (PHP, Magento) which may have affected my perception and understanding of the question. But while I also admit that it can be enough for a specialist, it barely has any good formulation.
I've flagged it VLQ, which was declined.

Please enlighten me if it was declined rightfully.

Comment: Ask those that reviewed it: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18581088

Comment: That's pretty terrible. So, regardless, is this post a good candidate for VLQ?

Comment: @Hexfire it is. Until people om the VLQ review queue just start robo reviewing :/.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Will you review ban the users who reviewed it as Looks OK? It seems quite obvious that they're robo-reviewers.

Comment: That also happened to me once. I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42023499/4284627) as VLQ and my flag got declined and the question later got closed as unclear what you're asking. I recommend never to flag questions as VLQ and flag them as should be closed instead (you didn't do anything wrong, but flagging as should be closed instead of VLQ will reduce the risk of your flags being incorrectly declined).

Comment: I see something similar in the Suggested Edits queue where people will do nothing except add a screenshot of code or other text and other reviewers will approve it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck  I believe that's a good tactic. I recently came to similar conclusion myself as I had exactly same situation with VLQ flag some time ago. Questions like this are indeed statistically much more often flagged as too broad or unclear, rather than low-quality (probably because the former two are low quality by definition, with just more precise/concrete formulation).

Comment: @BSMP I've seen a lot worse things in the Suggested Edits queue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13785359) someone approved an obvious spam edit. Luckily others rejected it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck and Hexfire: Flagging for closure is the correct course of action, not VLQ. [This is what happens with flags and queues](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/271271). Flagging a question as VLQ puts it in the Triage queue. Then from the Triage queue, someone else has to click on "Unsalvageable➞close" (which people notoriously don't do). The question *then* goes into the close-vote queue. If you just flag for closure to begin with, the question goes directly into the close-vote queue, saving everyone a bunch of time and putting the question in the correct queue.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Yes, there's been worse but usually the worst stuff usually gets rejected. The type of edit I described gets approved often enough that I have to think that they're getting Accepted on purpose by users who think it's OK, not just by robo reviewers spamming the Accept button.

Comment: Oh... you mean Triage is broken? No way... that can't be....

Comment: "Here is a picture of my car, Can you fix it?" At least, it's not a "Here is the picture of a car, I want a better performing one, with a drop down panel"

Comment: There is zero reason to ever cast a VLQ flag on a question.  All you're doing is sending the post to Triage in the *hopes* that enough users there will vote/flag for closure.  If you know that the post merits closure don't waste their time forcing someone *else* to vote/flag for closure (and also delaying how long it takes for the question to be closed), just vote to close yourself.  Basically the only reason to ever cast VLQ is because you think a post merits closure, but don't know for what reason, and if you don't know what reason it should be closed for *then you shouldn't be flagging*.

Comment: If you had simply flagged the post for closure to begin with not only would the post have moved to being closed faster, but you'd have removed any possibility of the reviewers not voting for closure.

Comment: @Servy yes, Makyen explained it perfectly clear in the comment above. This part sounds alogical to me, though: "(1) the _only_ reason to ever cast VLQ is...  _don't know for what reason_, (2) and, _if you don't know what reason_,... then you _shouldn't_ be flagging". So is there a valid reason to cast VLQ, in the end?

Comment: @Hexfire On a question, never.  On an answer...also never, but in that case simply because it has 100% overlap with NAA, and does the same thing when cast.

Comment: If casting VLQ on question surpasses simple good human reason, and is not merely a subjective point and causes real inconvenience across the system (brings in unnecessary step), why is this flag allowed for questions to begin with?

Comment: Pretty much the same about VLQ on answers, although I'm guessing you don't explain official SO guidelines here, as otherwise flag meaning completely renders void.

Comment: @Hexfire Once upon a time the flag has a reason that made sense (both for questions and for answers).  It was effectively made obsolete by later changes to the system, and hasn't been revisited since.

Comment: @Servy, I can think of 1 reason to cast a VLQ flag on a question, same reason for climbing Everest: because it's there. :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As Martijn points out, you unfortunately [had your flag reviewed by four problematic reviewers in triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18581088). They all made the wrong call, leading to your flag being incorrectly declined.

Those reviewers have been instructed as to where they went wrong.

Comment: Yes, that explained it. 3 same suggestions outweighed other votes, flag declined. Reason is clear, original question is settled.

Comment: just out of interest, what was wrong with the one who flagged it as 'Requires Editing'?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons "Requires Editing" is for when edits by editors other than the OP can fix the question. In this case, only the OP had any chance of salvaging the post.

Comment: @yivi  I can see why someone would think the question can be reformulated to something along the lines of 'On home page the path to the images are being passed through truncated {sample path}, whilst on the category' page they are being passed through completed {sample path}. Admittedly that's quite a lot of work for someone to just pick up edit-wise